# Каким образом сделать такую разметку?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

То, что должно быть на выходе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется следующая разметка:

```
<h2 class="block-title">Горячие новинки</h2>
```

Буду премного благодарен, друзья!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `span` с классом оберните слово `горячие` и отдельно отстилизуйте в черный цвет, а полосу с помощью псевдокласса `:after` создайте.
На скорую руку как-то так:

```css
.block-title {
  color: #000;
}
.block-title span {
  color: #650815;
}
.block-title:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 76px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="block-title"><span>Горячие</span> новинки</h2>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как сделать полосу, чтобы она не заходила не текст?

Comment: сейчас накидаю набросок, псевдоклас after можно стилизировать...

Comment: Реализовал через костыли :) Спасибо, что дали нужный вектор.

Comment: дополнил ответ, если смог помоч то отметте ответ верным)

Comment: Да, конечно! Спасибо! Рад, что есть такие люди!

Comment: @ВиталийДемчук, а если так: https://jsfiddle.net/otwgyt4r/ ?

Comment: @Other [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535809/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83#answer-535821) вариант наилучший как по мне.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - без подсчётов и костылей, с использованием `flex`:

```css
.block-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #be9f7e;
  display: flex;
}
.block-title:after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #be9f7e;
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.block-title span {
  color: black;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="block-title"><span>Горячие</span> новинки</h2>
```

Comment: Отличный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

sass:

```
.views_title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #fff;

  .title {
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 10px;
  } 

  .special {
    color: $main_color;
  }

  &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid $main_color;
  }
}
```

html:

```
<h2 class="views_title">
  <span class="title">
    Горячие <span class="special">новинки</span>
  </span>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.block-title span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #dda058;
}

.block-title:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 6px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dda058;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="block-title">Горячие <span>новинки</span></h2>
```